# No namespace for classes generated by Android Binding Library

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am currently trying to bind a `.jar` library to use in Xamarin.

I have added it a binding library project and tried to build (as suggested in the [Xamarin guide for Android binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-a-jar)).

But when I build I get a ton of errors. All stemming from the fact that certain classes are being generated sans namespaces.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Runtime;

namespace  { //<-- See here, no name

// Metadata.xml XPath class reference: path="/api/package[@name='']/class[@name='P']"
[global::Android.Runtime.Register ("/P", DoNotGenerateAcw=true)]
public partial class P : global::Java.Lang.Object {
```

When I decompile the `.jar`, I see that those classes are in the root of the `.jar`. Could that be an issue?

Has anyone come across this issue, and if so, how did you fix it?

Comment: Use Metadata.xml/Xpath to move (or remove, rename,...) those into a C# namespace of your choice if those classes are needed, otherwise remove them : https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb

Comment: @SushiHangover I am trying to do that but, because it is in the root, I can't seem to figure out what to put in the `package[@name='{package_name}']` section. The files are in the root directory so there isn't anything to put in that field and it doesn't work if you leave it out.